# SetTextColor has a transparent fill

Tags: c++, windows, dc

so i have a c++ program that uses dc to draw on screen. I have a text that i want to make black, here's the code

```
  RECT textRect;
  textRect.left = 200;//adjusting the position of the text, x
  textRect.top = 405;//adjusting the position of the text, y
  textRect.right = combinedSize.cx;
  textRect.bottom = combinedSize.cy;
  SetTextColor(hdcDest, RGB(0, 0, 0));
  SetBkMode(hdcDest, TRANSPARENT);
  DrawText(hdcDest, text.c_str(), -1, &textRect, DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER | DT_SINGLELINE);
```

however the fill of the code is transparent, however the outline changes when i try to change the color of a text. Does anyone know how to fix it? I've also tried adding a background to this text but it is slightly larger then area of the text.

Comment: Could you show a picture of what you want, and what you get instead? It's not clear from your description.

Comment: You'd have to use the exact same font and size to get the outline to not change.  Use CreateFont(), etc.